# Incorrect syntax near the keyword 'ON'

Tags: c#, sql, t-sql

While executing following query, it shows error, "Incorrect syntax near the keyword 'ON'."

```
string query = "SELECT Employee_Master.Employee_Code AS 'EmployeeCode',
       Employee_Master.Employee_ID AS'Employee_ID',
       Employee_Master.FIRST_NAME +' '+ ISNULL(Employee_Master.MIDDLE_NAME,'') +' ' +Employee_Master.LAST_NAME AS'emp_Name',
       Task_Master.Task_Code AS'Task_Code',
       Task_Master.Task_Name AS'Task_Name',
       Task_Completion_Status_Master.Task_Complition_Status_Name AS 'Task_status',
       Work_Submission_Master.Submission_Date AS'Submission_Date' " + "FROM Work_Submission_Detail INNER JOIN"+ "Work_Submission_Master ON Work_Submission_Detail.Work_Submission_ID = Work_Submission_Master.Work_Submission_ID INNER JOIN"+ "Task_Master ON dbo.Work_Submission_Detail.Task_ID = Task_Master.Task_ID INNER JOIN"+ "Task_Completion_Status_Master ON "+ "Work_Submission_Detail.Completion_Status = Task_Completion_Status_Master.Task_Complition_Status_ID INNER JOIN"+ "Employee_Master ON Work_Submission_Master.Employee_ID = Employee_Master.Employee_ID";
```

Comment: Tip when working with inline queries: format (read: make them look prettier than this) and run it directly on your SQL Server environment. You're more likely to see typo errors like this.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to put space after `INNER JOIN`

> INNER JOIN"+ "Work_Submission

Should be

```
INNER JOIN "+ "Work_Submission
```

Wherever you have used the `INNER JOIN`, you missed that space. So put it wherever you have used this.

Using such large inline query, I would suggest you to use `Stored Procedure` instead of inline query, that will help you write query with ease as well as readability along with less chance to have typo errors.

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
string strqry = "SELECT EM.Employee_Code as 'EmployeeCode', EM.Employee_ID as'Employee_ID', EM.FIRST_NAME +' '+ ISNULL(EM.MIDDLE_NAME,'') +' ' +EM.LAST_NAME as'emp_Name', TM.Task_Code as'Task_Code', TM.Task_Name as'Task_Name',Task_Completion_Status_Master.Task_Complition_Status_Name as 'Task_status',WSM.Submission_Date as'Submission_Date' " +
"FROM Work_Submission_Detail WSD INNER JOIN "+
"Work_Submission_Master WSM ON WSD.Work_Submission_ID = WSM.Work_Submission_ID INNER JOIN "+
"Task_Master TM ON dbo.WSD.Task_ID = TM.Task_ID INNER JOIN "+
"Task_Completion_Status_Master ON "+
"WSD.Completion_Status = Task_Completion_Status_Master.Task_Complition_Status_ID INNER JOIN "+
"Employee_Master EM ON WSM.Employee_ID = EM.Employee_ID";
```